# PySpark dataframe subtraction

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have two PySpark dataframes,

df1

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|  100|
|  200|
|  300|
```

df2

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|  300|
|  400|
|  500|
```

How should I calculate df2 - df1 as the result showed below without using Pandas?

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|  200|
|  200|
|  200|
```

Comment: Since Spark dataframe is unordered, you need an ordering column or identifiable column to map the 2 dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a column like 'id' as index.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,100),(2,200),(3,300)], ['id', 'count1'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(1,300),(2,400),(3,500)], ['id', 'count2'])
(
    df1.join(df2, ['id'], "outer")
        .withColumn("count", col("count2") - col("count1"))
        .sort('id')
    .show()
)
# +---+------+------+-----+
# | id|count1|count2|count|
# +---+------+------+-----+
# |  1|   100|   300|  200|
# |  2|   200|   400|  200|
# |  3|   300|   500|  200|
# +---+------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `monotonically_increasing_id()` to order the dfs and then join by row number using a window funtion:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(100,),(200,),(300,)]).toDF('count')
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([(300,),(400,),(500,)]).toDF('count')

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window().orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id())
df1 = df1\
          .withColumn('row_num', F.row_number().over(w))\
          .select('row_num', F.col('count').alias('count_1'))
df2 = df2.withColumn('row_num', F.row_number().over(w))\
          .select('row_num', F.col('count').alias('count_2'))

df1\
    .join(df2, 'row_num')\
    .withColumn('count', F.col('count_2') - F.col('count_1'))\
    .show()

+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|row_num|count_1|count_2|count|
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
|      1|    100|    300|  200|
|      2|    200|    400|  200|
|      3|    300|    500|  200|
+-------+-------+-------+-----+
```